# Get-VMMServer equivalent in c# using WMI root\virtualization namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces, wmi, virtualization, virtual-machine

I am searching through the Virtualization namespace looking for a class that will provide me with the VMM server of a Host. I cant seem to find any class that has a VMM Server field or property.

I am looking for the Virtual Machine Management Server that a Host gets attached to.

Does this information exist in WMI virtualization namespace? Registry? Config file?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late maybe but it's in the following Registry key which you can view with this command:

REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest\Parameters" /s

I'm trying to find a way to get it from WMI myself.